# Python regular expression question - sub string but not prepended with

Tags: python, regex

:)

I'm trying to sub foo to bar, but only if it's not prepended with ie. /. So...

foobar should change to barbar, but /foobar not.

I've tried to add [^/] at beginning of my re, but that doesn't work if foo is at beginning of string.

I hate regular expressions! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
>>> re.search('(?<!/)foo', 'foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f44891518b8>
>>> re.search('(?<!/)foo', '/foo')
>>> re.search('(?<!/)foo', 'barfoo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4489151850>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using
    \bfoo\b

\b is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), it deals with a lot of common cases like beginning of line, whitespace, etc.